# Select text of the control when validation occurs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I want to highlight text in control when validation occurs.

How can I achieve this?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(source, args) {
    var txt = document.getElementById('<%= txtAge.ClientID %>');
    if (args.Value.length >= 3) {
        txt.style.background = '#66CCFF';
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        txt.style.background = 'none';
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
    
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfldtxtAge" ErrorMessage="enter the value" ControlToValidate="txtAge"  runat="server" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ctmtxtAge" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="changeColor" ControlToValidate="txtAge" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator1" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I use this code for highlighting background of control, but I need to highlight the text of control.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
 txt.select();
```

instead of

```
txt.style.background = '#66CCFF';
```

please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: thanz a lot.i got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 txt.style.color= '#66CCFF' instead of  txt.style.background = '#66CCFF';
```

use this thing to change the color of the text